# Mockito : Unable to create mock for external DAL library

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, springmockito

I am running Mockito latest version(3.11.2) with JUnit and Spring and getting this error creating mock -

```
`Fix required:this map must be added to the appropriate MapInitializer. Trying to recover from this error and continue... 
at com./.integ.dal.map.BaseMap2.checkInitialized(BaseMap2.java:1540)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53) 13:18:19 main ERROR com./.integ.dal.map.BaseMap2
Failed to recover from previous errors and late-initialize the class=class com./.integ.uhslogicalhost.UhsLogicalHostMap. This class' initialization cannot be post-poned due to some dependencies.  Fix required: add this class and its dependencies to a proper MapInitializer,and make sure that their DAL Init Policy is set to true in DALInitPolicy.properties. Exception: com./.integ.dal.DalRuntimeException: No token parser factory was found for a driverType of sql.
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class com./.integ.adscampaignitem.AdsCampaignItemDAO.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.
You are seeing this disclaimer because Mockito is configured to create inlined mocks.
You can learn about inline mocks and their limitations under item #39 of the Mockito class javadoc.
Underlying exception : org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Cannot instrument class com./.integ.adscampaignitem.AdsCampaignItemDAO because it or one of its supertypes could not be initialized
at com./.app.ploebat.client.SellerAdsDalClientTest.testGetItems(SellerAdsDalClientTest.java:94)  
Fix required: add this class and its dependencies to a proper MapInitializer,and make sure that their DAL Init Policy is set to true in DALInitPolicy.properties. Exception: com./.integ.dal.DalRuntimeException: No token parser factory was found for a driverType of sql.
No token parser factory was found for a driverType of sql.
at com./.integ.dal.map.BaseMap2.checkInitialized(BaseMap2.java:1559)
Process finished with exit code 255`
```

Following line of code is causing this error-

```
AdsDAO adsDAO = mock(AdsDAO.class);
```

I have tried using latest version on byte-buddy as well, it doesn't work.

Here is AdsCampaignItemDAO.class-

```
public class AdsCampaignItemDAO extends BaseDao2 {
private static volatile AdsCampaignItemDAO s_instance;
private static GenericMap<AdsCampaignItem> s_map;
private static AdsCampaignItemCodeGenDoImpl m_noFetchProtoDO;
private static AdsCampaignItemCachedSeqGenDAO s_seq = AdsCampaignItemCachedSeqGenDAO.getInstance();

public static AdsCampaignItemDAO getInstance() {
    if (s_instance == null) {
        synchronized(AdsCampaignItemDAO.class) {
            if (s_instance == null) {
                s_instance = new AdsCampaignItemDAO();
            }
        }
    }

    return s_instance;
}

protected AdsCampaignItemDAO() {
    if (!m_mapInitialized) {
        initMap();
    }

}

public static void initMap() {
    if (!m_mapInitialized) {
        GenericMap<AdsCampaignItem> map = GenericMap.getMap(AdsCampaignItem.class);
        map.setDalVersion("3.0");
        m_mapInitialized = true;
        s_map = map;
        m_noFetchProtoDO = new AdsCampaignItemCodeGenDoImpl((BaseDao2)null, map);
        m_noFetchProtoDO.setAdsCampaignItemId(-1L);
        AdsCampaignItemCachedSeqGenDAO.init();

        try {
            map.registerToupleProvider("ADS_CAMPAIGN_ITEM", AdsCampaignItemToupleProvider.getAdsCampaignItemToupleProvider());
        } catch (NullPointerException var2) {
            throw new DalRuntimeException("DAL not properly initialized.");
        }

        initHintGroups(map);
        map.setUpdateSets(getUpdateSets(map));
        map.init();
    }
}
```

}

Here is the code for BaseMap2, looks like the issue is in this class -

```
public abstract class BaseMap2 {
protected BaseDo2 m_DOProtoCopyInstance;
protected Map<Integer, ReadSet> m_readSetsById = new IntKeyHashMap();
private Map<Object, Integer> m_mapDynamicReadSetsByGeneratedKey;
private AtomicInteger m_DynamicReadSetIndex;


protected BaseMap2() {
    if (this instanceof DynamicReadSetMap) {
        this.m_readSetsById = Collections.synchronizedMap(this.m_readSetsById);
        this.m_mapDynamicReadSetsByGeneratedKey = new ConcurrentHashMap();
        this.m_DynamicReadSetIndex = new AtomicInteger(-5000);
    }
}
```

}

[The part of code that generates exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cq14O.png)

Comment: can you add AdsCampaignItemDAO source code here pls? thx

Comment: Is there an interface that can be used instead of trying to mock a concrete class?  Or does the concreate class have other constructors, where mocked configuration could be passed in?  As @shikida suggested, more context is needed to help!

Comment: I just added the class that I'm trying to mock @shikida

Comment: Now we need the source code for BaseMap2 because the error comes from BaseMap2.checkInitialized(BaseMap2.java:1540) - probably related to UhsLogicalHostMap dependencies. Also, look at the message "No token parser factory was found for a driverType of sql" -- is it trying to dynamically load some jdbc driver that is not present in your test code?

Comment: with object properly mocked, any external method will not be executed right? I don't understand why is it going there

Comment: I added code for BaseMap2, not able to add full code because of character limit but I added the constructor part.

Comment: what mockito does behind the scenes is to intercept the class methods (it's basically a wrapper around the original class) using bytecode manipulation (I think), but still, you need to satisfy the dependencies. In this case, it seems the class relies on some dynamic class loading (probably via reflection) that can't be executed, thus, causing the problem, IMO

Comment: So I think what we need here in BaseMap2 is the method that contains BaseMap2.java:1540 -- I bet it tries to dynamically load some class using reflection, but this class is not available during runtime on your test (because it's not in the test classpath)

Comment: I just added the lines of code that's causing exception(in the image). You are right about the dynamic class that Mockito is trying to load here. I can't make changes in the library. What would be the workaround?
I can see the class is available in class path for tests.